# AWS Instance Stopped Responding, FrontEnd backEnd & ssh connection issue until restarted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

Actual when I try to connect to instance it won't get connected and my server frontend and backend is stopped(no response from server). Thus when I **stop and start** the instance again it **start working again**, later next day same**(No Response from server)**. but if I see my instance status on AWS console dashboard it shows **Running**

Comment: This would be due to _something_ happening on the instance. Start by checking the CPU Utilization metrics in CloudFormation to see if something strange it happening. Next, restart the instance and login, then check the log files on your frontend/backend server. The fact that it is running on EC2 is probably not relevant -- the cause would be something to do with the software, processes and operating system running on the instance.

Comment: Ok will Check it out and get back here